# How to check result code before getting json from server in retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

## How to check result code 0 or 1, and if its 1 load data part, if its 0 doesn't check data.

There is any way to solve this problem

1.when the user logged in successfully the server returns the below JSON it contains data part and includes token
result for success:

```
{
    "result_code": 1,
    "message": "Login Success",
    "data": {
        "token": "4c9ed572de5aa01467d83fb3101fceb7",
        "name": "sachin"
    }
}
```

2. The login failure the server returns an empty data part

result for failure:

```
{"result_code":0,"message":"Invalid Username Or Password","data":[]}
```

Comment: If don't mind so you have to use Volley. It is easy as a comparison to  Retrofit

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<YourModel> call, Response<YourModel> response) {
    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
      if (response.getResult_code() == 0) {
       // Handle unauthorized case
      } else {
       // Handle Data & proceed further
       }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use these POJO classes in retrofit

Main Class

```
public class MyPojo
{
private Data data;

private String result_code;

private String message;

public Data getData ()
{
    return data;
}

public void setData (Data data)
{
    this.data = data;
}

public String getResult_code ()
{
    return result_code;
}

public void setResult_code (String result_code)
{
    this.result_code = result_code;
}

public String getMessage ()
{
    return message;
}

public void setMessage (String message)
{
    this.message = message;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "ClassPojo [data = "+data+", result_code = "+result_code+", message = "+message+"]";
}
```

DataClass

```
public class Data
{
private String name;

private String token;

public String getName ()
{
    return name;
}

public void setName (String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

public String getToken ()
{
    return token;
}

public void setToken (String token)
{
    this.token = token;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "ClassPojo [name = "+name+", token = "+token+"]";
}
```

}

When the retrofit gives response checks whether the data part is null or not. Using

```
response.getData().getData() != null
```

If it is not null it means the server had given the data else login failure from the server.

Answer (score 0):

check after response get into your model class like this

```
 if(response.isSuccessfull)
    {
    modelClass = response.body();

 int result_code = modelClass.getResultCode();

    //get result code

    if(result_code == 0)
    {

     // your implementation

    }else

    {
     // your implementation
    }

    }
```